# How would you repeat something on the X and Y axis in Inkscape?

Tags: automation, vector-graphics, inkscape

I would like to use the paint bucket to fill in the background with black and white circles evenly spaced apart.  What is this called?

Comment: Try looking up offset duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the clone tool :

- Select the object
- Menu -> Edition -> Clone... -> Create Tiled Clones
- "Symmetry" tab, then "P1 -> translation"
- Choose the number of rows/columns you want
- ???
- Profit

Then, you can fill arbitrary shapes with the result, by selecting all the clones, then 
Menu Object -> Patters -> Object to Pattern (Alt-i)

Then in any shape you have, you can fill it with this newly created pattern.